# Retry MySQL replication error instead of skip

Tags: mysql, replication

I have replication error like

`Last_Error: Error 'Unknown column ..` on my slave, because for some reasons the schema are not the same (we are using statement bases replication).

Now, I've fixed the slave table and want to rerun the error query, for most tutorial telling me to skip the last statement using..

> SET GLOBAL SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER = 1;

However, I don't want to skip, I want to retry the last statement, is it possible?

Comment: Just start replication again.  When you start replication, it skips the number of entries in the log specified in GLOBAL_SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER.  If that number isn't set or it's set to 0, then it'll skip 0.

Answer (score 0):

You could correct the table structure on the slave with an `ALTER TABLE` to ensure that the table structure is the same as the master and then `START SLAVE`.

If you don't understand how you got to this point you may have many more differences. Consider re-initializing the slave from a backup/master.

If the replication continues but you still want to know if there are other differences [pt-table-sync](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-table-sync.html) can search/fix differences.